# Once you find match exit in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'am working to find a match in text file from a shell script and get the desired output

the format of text file is like this :

```
    var1 = X
    var2 = X
    var3 = X
    var4 = BDH
```

My shell script is like this for now

```
    values=$(grep -hnr -A2 "$another_value_to_match" exemple.txt | cut -d "=" -f2)
    find_all_values=$(ls -d $DIR/["$values"]* | xargs -n 1 basename)
```

**another_value_to_match** is a variable i'am taking from another function and should contain (var1, var2, var3, var4).
**find_all_values** is trying to look into a large folder for sub-folders that start with (X, or B or D or H).

My problem is that if **another_value_to_match** == var4 everything is fine and works correctly because it's the last line in the text file but if **another_value_to_match** == var1 or any other value I get as output : **X X X BDH**.

My question is : How to stop after finding match whether it's in the first line of text file or the last line ? to simplify stuff if

```
   if (another_value_to_match == var2)
   values=$(grep -hnr -A2 "$another_value_to_match" exemple.txt | cut -d "=" -f2 | add_something_to_pipe)
   echo $values
   values == X
```

Comment: Are you asking how to write an `if` statement? If so there are plenty of resources out there to tell you how to do that. e.g. https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Comment: Hello @Machavity no i'am not asking about if statement that was a pseudo code I want to add something to the pipe in place of **add_something_to_pipe** to exit code when he find match in any line and not just in the last line

Comment: Why are you using the `grep` with `-hnr -A2` options? What are those options good for in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
another_value_to_match="var1"
sed -n "/$another_value_to_match *=/{s:^.*=::;p;q}" example.txt
```

Explanation:

- `sed -n` - run `sed` with option `-n` (not auto print)
- `/$another_value_to_match *=/` - find a line containing that text
- `s:^.*=::` - delete everything up to `=` (inclusive)
- `p;q` - print, then quit `sed`

If you need to get the last value, then run `tac` to have things in reverse:

```
tac example.txt | sed -n "/$another_value_to_match *=/{s:^.*=::;p;q}"
```

(sorry for my broken English)

Comment: Hello @Bach Lien , your english is clear no worry about it. I have upvoted this answer and this one helped me acheive what I was looking for to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting what you think.  The instruction

```
cut -d "=" -f2
```

is giving you **everything** after the "=" as a parameter, **including the leading space character**.  You should use

```
awk -v testor="$another_value_to_match" '{ if( $1 == testor ){ print $3 } }'
```

or

```
awk -v testor="$another_value_to_match" '{ if( $1 == testor ){ print $NF } }'
```

to get a clean return of only the desired string/value, *assuming that the value is a single string*.

Things get more complicated if the value is multi-string, but I think this will get you thought processes working in the right direction.